# aws S3 sync command is not working for replicated objects in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I have replicated the objects in S3 from one account to another. After replicating the objects into another account, I have tried  using aws S3 sync command from the replicated account to copy the objects into ubuntu server. However, it is showing as Access Denied. Tried using aws S3 sync command with source bucket, it was able to download the images from source S3 bucket.

Bucket policy:

> 

```
 {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Principal": {
>                 "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::acnt"
>             },
>             "Action": [
>                 "s3:ListBucket",
>                 "s3:GetObject",
>                 "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
>             ],
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::name/*",
>                 "arn:aws:s3:::name"
>             ]
>         }
>     ] 
}
```

Comment: check once what bucket policy is set and IAM user which you are using are having right access or not. Add more details like bucket policy snapshot

Comment: @aviboy2006  when I tried replicating the objects within the same region, I'm able to download the images(using s3 cp/sync) from the destination bucket. However, for the multiple accounts, i am facing the issue.

Comment: what is this acnt?

Comment: @aviboy2006 the bucket policy that I have provided is for the destination bucket. By using the replication rule, I copied the objects between 2 accounts in aws.

Comment: you have to mentioned account id. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/ have you tried this ?

Comment: How are you "replicating" the objects between the initial buckets (that is, the first step rather than the second step)? Did you [Add the owner override option to the replication configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-change-owner.html)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Tried following the document that you have mentioned. Now, I'm able to download the images from the destination bucket. At first, I am unable to download because of of ownership issues on the destination bucket. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replicating Amazon S3 objects to a bucket owned by a different AWS Account, it is important to change the 'owner' of the objects to the new Account.

From [Changing the replica owner - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-change-owner.html):

> In replication, the owner of the source object also owns the replica by default. When source and destination buckets are owned by different AWS accounts, you can add optional configuration settings to change replica ownership to the AWS account that owns the destination bucket. You might do this, for example, to restrict access to object replicas. This is referred to as the owner override option of the replication configuration.
>
> To configure the owner override, you do the following:
>
> - Add the owner override option to the replication configuration to tell Amazon S3 to change replica ownership.
> - Grant Amazon S3 permissions to change replica ownership.
> - Add permission in the destination bucket policy to allow changing replica ownership. This allows the owner of the destination bucket to accept the ownership of object replicas.